# SImple Shell programming

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a shell script as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/manoj/
$j;
j = $ (find -name ".mkv" | wc -l)

echo "$j"
```

whenever I try to execute the script, I get the following error.

```
line 5: j: command not found
```

Can someone please advise me as where I am going wrong?

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend here. Also the `$j;` line isn't doing anything useful for you (or anything at all for that matter).

Comment: Please try to make the title of your question as relevant as possible to the issue that you are having. This enables other people to benefit from the answers that have been posted here and also helps identify issues that have already been solved in other questions.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be space between variable and expression for equals (=) operator. Also there is no need to declare the variable $j

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/manoj/
j=$(find -name ".mkv" | wc -l)
echo "$j"
```

Comment: Thanks rajuGT. Space was the issue as you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: no problem. Also there is no need to declare the variable. :) just use it. and while referring use $<variable>

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/manoj/
j=$(find -name ".mkv" | wc -l)

echo "$j"
```

Remove space before and after '='

Comment: Got to know that a space could ruin my entire script.
Thanks slavik.

Comment: Why have you left in the `$j;` line?

Comment: it might be removed :) (removed)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some error in the code itself ,

```
cd /home/manoj/
j=$(find -name "*.mkv"|wc -l) # Remove the space between j,=,$
#while using find you need to use the file name pattern as '*.mkv' 
echo "$j"
```